# Why is filter not working when inside another ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a button based filter, but as soon as I attach the filter to ng-repeat it does not work anymore (NOTE, the objects that need to be filtered are in another ng-repeat).

```
<!-- This works -->
<div ng-click="myFilter = {name: 'Test'}">button</div>

<!-- This does not work -->
<span ng-repeat="(key, button) in gl_categories">
    <div ng-click="myFilter = {name: 'Test'}">{{button}}</div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS developers recommend do not write code on the templates. The templates must be used like read only.

In your case, the problem is because the ng-repeat create a new scope for each iteration. You are writing on the iteration scope.

Try to use a function instead of the manual assigment.

```
$scope.setFilter = function(value){
  $scope.myFilter = {name: value}
}
```

later

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, button) in gl_categories">
    <div ng-click="setFilter('test')">{{button}}</div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `ngRepeat` creates its own child scope, and each time that click event happens, another `myFilter` variable gets created on that scope. You can use an object, then set the object property (this will bubble up)

```
<div ng-click="x.myFilter = {name: 'Test'}">button</div>

<span ng-repeat="(key, button) in gl_categories">
    <div ng-click="x.myFilter = {name: 'Test'}">{{button}}</div>
</span>
```

I'd recommend reading the following post for an awesome explanation: [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)